Langchain create_react_agent stream stopped on the very first AIMessage and doesn't provide the full answer
I have followed the officiel langchain documentation https://js.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/tutorials/sql_qa to create an llm react agent that can query sqlite database:
`agent_executor = create_react_agent(chat_model, tools, messages_modifier=system_message)
for s in agent_executor.stream(
    {"messages": [HumanMessage(content="Which country's customers spent the most?")]}
):
    print(s)
    print("----")`

The stream stopped on the very first AIMessage ans it didn't continue until the complete thouht as mentionned in the guide. This is what I got after running the code above:

{'agent': {'messages': [AIMessage(content="To determine which
country's customers spent the most, we need to look at the relevant
tables in the database. First, let's list all the tables to understand
the structure of the database.", additional_kwargs={'refusal': None},
response_metadata={'token_usage': {'completion_tokens': 36,
'prompt_tokens': 549, 'total_tokens': 585}, 'model_name': 'gpt-4o',
'system_fingerprint': 'fp_f5a70d8dc9', 'finish_reason': 'stop',
'logprobs': None}, id='run-fa55841d-026a-4bd9-9060-24740c0ec6ad-0',
usage_metadata={'input_tokens': 549, 'output_tokens': 36,
'total_tokens': 585})]}}

Can anyone tell us if he was able to get the same result as it was mentionned in the documentation ?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry, it was indeed not very clear. I hope it's better now !
